# If $x>5$, then there exists a $y>0$ such that $x^2>25 + y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm working on a basic proof for my intro proof course.  The text is Analysis with an Introduction to Proof by Lay. This question comes from section 2.  I am asked to prove or disprove the following:

> If $x>5$, then there exists a $y>0$ such that $x^2>25 + y$

So my work follows:

Proof: Suppose $x$ is an arbitrary real number greater than 5 and choose $y=x-5$, then
\begin{align*}
25 + y & = 25 + (x-5)\\
& = 20+x,
\end{align*}
which is less than $x^2$ when $x>5$.  Therefor for all $x>5$ there exists a $y$ namely, $y=x-5$ such that $x^2>y+25$.

So that is what I have.  At this point I am not entirely convinced that I have shown enough to proove my statement.  I am still very green when it comes to writing proofs, and I feel as if my conculsion is not obvious.  I think I am on the right track here, but I could use some direction. Also I have been scolded more than once for doing proofs backwards, I am hoping that I have alleviated this in this problem, but again, this is all still pretty new.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take rather $z=x-5>0$. Then expand $x^2=(5+z)^2$. You'll see that you can take $y=z^2>0$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. But note that finding any one value of y which satisfies the condition is **sufficient** for **existance proofs**.

Comment: Right, the existential quantifer vs. the universal quantifier correct? I only need to find 1 y which satisfies for all x...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you should elaborate on why $x^2>20+x$. This inequality is the same as $(x-5)(x+4)=x^2-x-20>0$ which is true when $x>5$.

Alternatively, just use $y=\frac{x^2-25}{2}$ to lead to a quick proof.

Comment: can you possibly elaborate on this, I think I see why this works, however, my professor was not satified with the above - that is, I had not sufficiently shown why (in my proof) that 20+x is less than $x^2$.  I can see why taking the above works, I just can't articulate it correctly I guess.